# Failed Start for Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine on Linux

Tags: sql-server, database, ubuntu-16.04, sql-server-2017, sql-server-linux

I have installed mssql on Ubuntu 16.04. following are the details of sql server.
ms sql `(14.0.3015.40-1)` i.e `SQL server 2017`.

when I run the configuration command `#sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup`
I got error `sudo: /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup: command not found`

I have stopped and restarted but of no use.

When I check the status by command `#systemctl status mssql-server`

I got

```
mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-02 16:15:29 IST; 4min 20s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 28050 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 28050 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Feb 02 16:15:28 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 02 16:15:28 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 02 16:15:29 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 02 16:15:29 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Feb 02 16:15:29 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 02 16:15:29 chetan-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

I have googled and tried all possible options. But unable to start SQL server.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: If the path to the command is wrong restarting the machine or the service won't fix it. Check the path

Answer (score 3):

I had the same two problems.

First, I was referencing *very old* documentation that applied to an early (preview) release for RHEL, and so I was using the wrong command. The correct command is:

```sh
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

Second, the service was failing to start because my virtual machine did not have enough RAM available (SQL Server on Linux requires at least 2GiB of RAM available.) The documentation I was referred to incorrectly stated that only 0.5GiB was required, this is incorrect and `journalctl` was not providing any useful information about the start failure.

After configuring available memory to 2GiB and using the correct `mssql-conf` command I was able to successfully configure and start an MSSQL Server instance on Linux.

References:

- [Configure SQL Server on Linux with the mssql-conf tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft Docs)
- [KB052969: FIX: Minimum memory limit set to 2GB to install or start SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4052969-fix-minimum-memory-limit-set-to-2gb-to-install-or-start-sql-server-2017-e7d95b55-7106-bf95-e82a-ae1fe8c21479) (Microsoft Support)
- [Installation guidance for SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft Docs)

Answer (score 2):

The error says that the *executable* wasn't found in this path, not that the service couldn't start.

According to the [installation instructions for Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu#install) you need to run `mssql-conf setup` to configure the server :

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

not `sqlservr-setup`

Comment: Does this service remove existing databases? I'm unable to start my database engine and am trying to reconfigure it.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the RAM size to 3GB on my VM resolved the issue for me.